# comparing One String With Multiple Other Strings

Tags: c#

i have a winform C# sql app in which i'm retrieving data and storing in strings. like so,.

```
string a1 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_1"]);
                    string a2 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_2"]);
                    string a3 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_3"]);
                    string a4 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_4"]);
                    string a5 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_5"]);
                    string a6 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_6"]);
                    string a7 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_7"]);
                    string a8 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_8"]);
                    string a9 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_9"]);
                    string a10 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_10"]);
                    string a11 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_11"]);
                    string a12 = Convert.ToString(srj[@"Sub_12"]);
```

here i'm retrieving 12 values. now i want to compare each of these values with some strings like a1, a2...a29. if both the strings match the a corresponding check box with the string has to be checked.
but the way i see it, i have to compare 30 string with first value, then 30 strings  with the second value, and so forth.

is there any way to do this using some other method?

Comment: If you have to compare all string with eachother, there is no other way.

Comment: a forloop and using `Sub + i.ToString()` comes to mind... But instead of converting all to string, can you not compare their real types?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: so i have to write code for 460 conditions?

Comment: @Sayse i converted them to strings thinking it will be much easier to compare..

Comment: Or store the values in an array and use a LINQ expression

Comment: @PeterSmith i've not worked much with LINQ. Can you please give an example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm.

It allow you to  locates elements of a finite set of strings within an input string matching all patterns from the set simultaneously.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

OK  - try this

```
String[] myList1 = new String[] {"a","ab", "ba", "cc", "ab"};
String[] myList2 = new String[] {"a","abc", "ba", "c2c", "ab1", "cccc", "ba"};

var keyResult = myList1.Where(x=>myList2.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Gives an array containing "a" and "ba". The two arrays do not have to be the same length. It also deals with repeated items as a single item.

And then there is the set intersection method as well.

```
var keyResult2 = myList1.Intersect(myList2).ToArray();
```